Vector space generated by translates
I'm going through a proof in the book Introduction to Banach Spaces: Analysis and Probability and I don't understand some things (I believe that the context is enough, because this is just the beginning of the proof, $\lambda_i$ are just some natural numbers)


How does this space $E$ look like?
What does it mean for a space to be generated by the translates?
How do you define $L^2$ norm there?

Edit. Ok, I think I understand that $E$ is just generated by $\sin{\lambda_jt}$ and $\cos{\lambda_jt}$, so it is closed under translations (but I don't really understand this $(-\Lambda) \cup \Lambda$ notation...). Still, I'm not sure how one defines $L^2(E)$ norm here.

Your deduction on $E$ is correct, so I will answer question 3.
It seems it is talking about the vector space of $L^2$ functions defined on some interval $I\subset \mathbb R^n$ with values in the vector space $E$. $E$ is a real vector space of finite dimension, so the space $L^2(I;E)$ is well-defined by identifying $E$ with $\mathbb R^{2N}$, and consequently identifying $L^2(I;E)$ with $L^2(I;\mathbb R^{2N})$, which in turn is canonically the same as the cartesian product of $2N$ copies of the usual $L^2(I)$. This space is well-defined, in particular it does not depend on the identification between $E$ and $\mathbb R^{2N}$, essentially because all norms on $E$ are equivalent.
Another way is simply to take any norm on $E$ and define
$$ \|\Phi\|_{L^2(E)}^2:=\int_I\|\Phi(\theta)\|_E^2d\theta. $$
Again, all norms on $E$ are equivalent, so whether the norm is finite or not for a given function does not depend on the choice of the norm on $E$.
It is possible that $I$ is a subset of the circle instead, it is hard to tell from what I read. This is all I can deduce from what you posted.
